# Swift 3 - Detail Disclosure Button Size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In storyboards, I currently have a custom tableview cell with a detail disclosure button in it. I increased the size of the cell and the font of the text label inside the cell, but now the detail disclosure button seems too small. I thought that the detail disclosure button would automatically increase in size as I made the cell bigger but it didn't. Is there a way to increase the size of the detail disclosure button?

Comment: No support for this. Use your own button instead.

Answer (score 1):

The default rule for almost anything in iOS: if something standard doesn't work then you have to implement custom one. So the easiest way to use custom accessory view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = // get cell
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(<your big image here>, for: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    cell.accessoryView = button
    // configure rest of the cell
    return cell
}
```